# Is there a more compact way to return a defer with AngularJS inside a function?

Tags: angularjs

I have this function that I use to call a $http, do some code and then return a success or reject promise.

```
function getActions() {
    var self = this;
    var defer = this.$q.defer();
    this.$http({
        url: '/api/Action/GetActions',
        method: "GET"
    })
        .success(function (data) {
            // Other code here for success
            self.Actions = data;
            return defer.resolve();
        })
    return defer.promise;
};
```

I would like to simplify this by just doing something like:

```
    return this.$http({
        url: '/api/Action/GetActions',
        method: "GET"
    })... etc
```

But if I do this then I will not be able to have any code in the success.

Can anyone tell me if there is any way that I can simplify the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function getActions()
{
    var self = this;

    var promise = this.$http({
        url: '/api/Action/GetActions',
        method: "GET"
    });

    promise.success(function (data) {
       // Other code here for success
       self.Actions = data;
    });

    return promise;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
function getActions() {
    return this.$http({
        url: '/api/Action/GetActions',
        method: "GET"
    })... etc
}
getActions().success(function(data){
    self.Actions = data;
    //...do other stuff on success as well
})
```

I personally like your original approach better though as it allows multiple then/success/fail blocks (one that happens after the http request and one optional that you can set in your returned promise). I actually use that approach all the time, even though it is a bit longer.

Answer (score 0):

The `success` and `error` methods added to the promise returned from `$http` don't behave as the standard `then` or  `catch` with respect to promise chaining. If you use `then`, you can chain promises as standard:

```
function getActions() {
  var self = this;
  return this.$http({
    url: '/api/Action/GetActions',
    method: "GET"
  }).then(function(response) {
    // Other code here for success
    self.Actions = response.data;
    return response;
  });
};
```

My advice is to just ignore the existence of `success` and `error`, and use `then` and `catch`.